# Cut off Preprocessor Line

Tags: c, macros, newline

In C, a preprocessor statement can be extended over multiple lines with a `\` character.

```
#define SWAP(a, b)  {                   \
                        a ^= b;         \
                        b ^= a;         \ 
                        a ^= b;         \
                    }
```

This will spread the macro out over several lines, but is there a way to cut a macro off *before* the end of a line? ie: I wanted to write code on the same line as a macro, but did not want it to be part of the macro. For example, is there a way to make the following possible?

```
#include <stdio.h> (some character here to end macro) int main(int argc, const char **argv)  { return 0; }
```

Is there a way to legally fit the preprocessor statement and the `main` function (or any other code) on the same line?

Comment: The macro preprocessor is quite mechanical, there's no way to short circuit it. Sorry. That said, there's nothing to keep you from putting code on the same line as preceding code.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?  C is cryptic enough without going for one-liners...which might be a semi-plausible reason, but it isn't a sensible reason.

Comment: There are better ways to write an [IOCCC](http://ioccc.org) entry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, not for the `#include` statements you're specifically mentioning in your question. And, though I haven't specifically checked<sup>(a)</sup>, that's probably the case for *all* preprocessing directives.

The standard states that the newline is an integral part of the syntax (from `C11 6.10.2 Source file inclusion`):

> A preprocessing directive of the form `# include <h-char-sequence>` **`new-line`** `...`

You *can* place a comment after an `#include` directive since replacements of comments with a single space happens in phase 3, whereas pre-processing directives are handled in phase 4 (see `C11 5.1.1.2 Translation phases`).

But that doesn't help you with trying to place non-comments like the `main()` function definition on the same line, that's still a no-no.

But my question to you would be: *why* on Earth would you want to do this? Simply output two lines and be done with it. It's not like we're suffering a world-wide shortage of newline characters :-)

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Jonathan Leffler *has* checked, so this statement is almost certainly correct.

From ISO/IEC 9899:2011, §6.10 Preprocessing directives:

> `# if` *constant-expression new-line group<sub>opt</sub>*
>   `# ifdef` *identifier new-line group<sub>opt</sub>*
>   `# ifndef` *identifier new-line group<sub>opt</sub>*
>   `# elif` *constant-expression new-line group<sub>opt</sub>*
>   `# else` *new-line group<sub>opt</sub>*
>   `# endif` *new-line*
>   `# include` *pp-tokens new-line*
>   `# define` *identifier replacement-list new-line*
>   `# define` *identifier lparen identifier-list<sub>opt</sub> ) replacement-list new-line*
>   `# define` *identifier lparen ... ) replacement-list new-line*
>   `# define` *identifier lparen identifier-list , ... ) replacement-list new-line*
>   `# undef` *identifier new-line*
>   `# line` *pp-tokens new-line*
>   `# error` *pp-tokens<sub>opt</sub> new-line*
>   `# pragma` *pp-tokens<sub>opt</sub> new-line*
>   `#` *new-line*

Comment: Does this mean that I can add a `\n` to simulate a new line. For example              `#include <stdio.h> \n int main(int argc, const char **argv)  { return 0; }` The split between the lines there was purely coincidental due to the format of the comment section. Should be read as one line

Comment: @Brian, no. For a start, escape sequences are transformed in phase 5. And, second, that's only done within character constants and string literals.

Answer (score 2):

First non white character of a line for a macro must be `#` and macro extends until the end of line(after line concatenation `\` characters). So you can not "Cut off Preprocessor Line".

If you want to do this for some crazy trick answer, you can better use `-D` or `/D` (which ever applicable) during compilation and avoid macro completely.

A sane programming requirement would never require any such feature.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my long career, I've found sane requirements to be very much in the minority :-)